# How to install PyGUI for Python3?

Tags: fedora, python, python3

I want to install PyGUI for Python3 on Fedora 23.

From [PyGUI](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python_gui/):

> Linux - requires pygtk (tested with pygtk-2.14.0 and Gtk+-2.14.7).

And by going to [PyGTK](http://www.pygtk.org/) it says:

> Note: New users are encouraged to use GTK+3 through the PyGObject bindings instead of using PyGTK with GTK+2. Windows users may still want to keep using PyGTK until more convenient installers are published.

So I managed to install `pygobject (3.18.2)` and `PyGUI (2.5.3)` for the Python3 environment. To make this clear, when I run `python3 -m pip list` I got (+ other stuff...):

- pygobject (3.18.2)
- PyGUI (2.5.3)

And I thought I was done with that but when I download and try the [blobedit.py example](http://www.cosc.canterbury.ac.nz/greg.ewing/python_gui/version/Demos/BlobEdit/blobedit.py) I got the following error ([complete error log here](http://pastebin.com/0ZiUEhrG)):

```
PyGIWarning: Gtk was imported without specifying a version first. Use gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0') before import to ensure that the right version gets loaded.
```

Sigh. I went to Python3 and try to import `gtk` and failed to found the module.

So, what would be the necessary steps for installing PyGUI for Python3 in Fedora 23? I'll appreciate any help! Thank you!